# Brachistochrone Problem to find out the path by which a bead travels in least time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

The question is to find the shape of the curve down whcih a bead sliding from rest and accelerated by gravity will slip(without friction) from one point to another in the least time.

So I proceeded with the kinematics equations, 
  $ S = ut + 1/2 at^ 2 $, 
from whcih  we finally get the time required to travel from a point P1 to P2 to be,

$ t= \int_{P1}^{P2} (2S/a)^{1/2} $ ,

where S is given by $ (1 +(dy/dx)^2)^{1/2} \,dx $,

The t becomes,

$ t = \int_{P1}^{P2} ((2(1+(dy/dx)^2)^{1/2} \,dx)/a)^{1/2} $,

Then I want to minimize the above function which is a function of $y,x$ and $dy/dx$ finally to get the equation of a cycloid.

We can do it by the method of variations, but I just tried to integrate the function directly , but integral involves $(dx)^{1/2}$, so I am not able to proceed furthur. Can anyone help me to give an idea to solve the integral involving fractional power of differential $dx$ .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've corrected your LaTeX. Remember to use "{}" to surround a block, such as in a superscript. Also, you can use "\," to put a little space before the "dx".

Comment: But actually it's not clear what you're doing. If you ever get $(dx)^{1/2}$, something went very wrong because you can never perform arithmetic operations on $dx$, since it often can be considered nothing more than a dummy symbol to indicate the variable that the integral is taken over.

Comment: What is $a$? Also, I don't think that your integral for the total time is correct. It is usually solved with the velocity being derived from the energy equations. Try here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html

Comment: The equation for $t$ involves $ (dx)^ 1/2 $. I can solve this equation using Euler Lagrange differential equation.

Comment: $a$ is acceleration due to gravity , and it's value is 9.8, it is a constant

Comment: @PravishaJohn: It is doubtful whether you can use the equation $S = ut + \frac 12 at^2$. That applies only to situation that the acceleration is constant. But the acceleration depends on the shape of the path, so is not a constant (and is not $a$ too)

Comment: Yes you are right